# Yarn & Monorepo: Prevent using local packages

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn/lerna monorepo with multiple packages that depend on each other. If I add `packageA` as a dependency to `packageB` and execute `yarn install` I see that `node_modules/packageA` is actually a symlink to `packages/packageA` instead of the published version of that package.

This creates problems on CI if `packageB` is build before `packageA` - the build fails because `node_modules/packageA` just points to the bare sources, without the build products (because `packageA` has not yet been built).

How can I force yarn to always download the published version of `packageA`?

---

`yarn --version`: 1.22.10

sidenote: If I wanted to use a local version of `packageA` instead, I would use `yarn link` or a local path instead of a version in `package.json`. Why is yarn defaulting to this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is: "focussed workspaces" - [see the guide here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/05/18/focused-workspaces/).

In my case, I added a file `packages/packageB/.yarnrc` that specifies to always use the `--focus` argument for `yarn install`:

```
--install.focus true
```

This will make sure that `packageB` has a copy of the published `packageA` in it's own `node_modules` folder.

However: This only works for one package at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just build packages in order of dependencies. So in your case it'd be something like this in your CI (assuming there is a script entry called "build" in package.json of the packages):

```
yarn workspace packageA run build
yarn workspace packageB run build
```

This way you control the order of builds,they complete successfully, and you don't have to force using published package.

Comment: actually, `lerna` will already build packages in order of dependency automatically. This removes the need for manually specifying the build order like this.